# Problem with \pagegoal

Tags: tex-core, lengths

At the beginning of page, `\pagegoal=\maxdimen` and therefore `\pagegoal-\pagetotal=0pt` or sometimes `\maxdimen`.  So I tested for `\maxdimen`, but got strange results (see MWE).

Is there a good way to get the remaining space on the page even at the beginning of a page?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\goodguess}
  
\begin{document}
\goodguess=\textheight
\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
\else
  \goodguess=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
\fi
\the\goodguess

\newpage
\goodguess=\textheight
\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen yes
\else
  \goodguess=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
\fi
\the\goodguess
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\goodguess=\textheight
\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
\else
  \goodguess=\pagegoal-\pagetotal
\fi
\the\goodguess
```

Here `\goodguess` is a skip, but `\textheight` is a dimen so expansion continues looking for `plus` so `\the\goodguess` expands, producing `0.0pt` and only then the assignment happens.

with

```
\goodguess=\textheight

\ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
\else
  \goodguess=\pagegoal-\pagetotal
\fi
\the\goodguess
```

The `\par` terminates the assignment so 550.0pt gets typeset

Note had the test been false,

```
\goodguess=\pagegoal-\pagetotal
```

would set `\goodguess=\pagegoal` then typeset `-` then start an assignment for `\pagetotal`

I think you meant

```
\goodguess=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
```

Comment: Would \relax do?

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, anything non expandable

Comment: @JohnKormylo or of course use latex syntax, there is a reason that is `\setlength\goodguess{\textheight}`

Comment: And I will need \par anyway for \pagegoal.  (And all this time I thought \setlength was puresly cosmetic, change for the sake of change.)