# How to reduce white space inside “.” automatically?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, line-breaking, kerning, newtx

Feeding

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtx}% this is what I use with many of other packages in a non-minimal example.
%% Text skips with glue being half of the value of the argument (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657443, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657448, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672701):
\newcommand{\flexibleHSkip}[1]{%
  \hskip#1
  plus.5\dimexpr\ifdim #1<0pt -\fi#1\relax
  minus.5\dimexpr\ifdim #1<0pt -\fi#1\relax
  \relax
}
\begin{document}\noindent
Consider the set \(Y\). Let \ldots\\
Consider the set \(Y\)\flexibleHSkip{-.1em}. \flexibleHSkip{.1em}Let \ldots\\
Consider the set \(Y\)\flexibleHSkip{-.1em}.\flexibleHSkip{.1em} Let \ldots\\
Consider the set \(Y\), and let \ldots\\
Consider the set \(Y\)\flexibleHSkip{-.1em}, \flexibleHSkip{.1em}and let \ldots\\
Consider the set \(Y\)\flexibleHSkip{-.1em},\flexibleHSkip{.1em} and let \ldots
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output with Computer Modern]

with standard fonts (Computer Modern) and

[image: output with NewTX]

with NewTX.  The versions with the reduced space between  and the punctuation mark seem better to me (and, hopefully, to you). The macro `\flexibleHSkip{…}` allows for stretching and shrinking to allow for prettier lines and paragraphs; if you don't care, you can use simple `\hskip-.1em` and `\hskip.1em` instead, for instance.

1. If we manually reduce white space before punctuation and add white space after punctuation, which version is correct™, i.e., causes less issues (I might imagine that line breaking could be hypothetically affected): `\flexibleHSkip{-.1em}PunctuationSymbol\flexibleHSkip{.1em}`  or `\flexibleHSkip{-.1em}PunctuationSymbol \flexibleHSkip{.1em}`. In other words, what should be the order of the regular space symbol   and `\flexibleHSkip{.1em}` after the punctuation mark?
2. How to get better spacing between “” and [“.” or “,”] automatically, without manual space deletions and insertions in the source document?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply pull the `.` in to the math, it will be taken from the mathrm font anyway and allows the font-specified kerns to take effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$Y$. ABC

$Y.$ ABC


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The kerning is reduced for Computer Modern but not for NewTX. But no negative kerning in math mode makes sense if the dot is the application operator, as in ..ℎ. = ((ℎ())). (Off topic: every time I typeset ℎ, I have to search for Planck's constant. This drives me crazy.) I'm not sure about the cases where the dot is the separator, as in λ-terms, such as λ x. λ .     .